# UK student visa refusal for not being a genuine student

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals

I am an Indian citizen and applied for my MSc in UK for the first time. However my visa got rejected on the basis of not being a genuine student, though all my documents are genuine. The rejection was based on the visa interview. I am planning to apply again for the same country and the same university for the January intake.

Will my rejection will haunt me and I what are the chances of getting the visa this time?

Comment: Also... we really need to see the content of your refusal notice.  You may have better luck at http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions as this site is about visitors to the UK and students who were refused under Appendix V of the rules. Your refusal was under Part 3 of the rules, which is OT for this site.

Comment: @GayotFow "OT" could mean "On Topic" just as easily as "Off Topic."  Consider that a new user might not know either acronym and might appreciate a link to http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @WBT, good tip. I'll remember to spell it out